# UITableViewDataSource doesn't recognize cellForRowAt indexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, datasource

Here are the relevant sections of code:

```
class SeriesViewController: BaseViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

...

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

...

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CustomTVCell {
```

And yet, Xcode insists that:

*Type 'SeriesViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'*

And politely asks:

*Do you want to add protocol stubs?*

I tried doing that, then moved all the code from the existing delegate K, but it still says it doesn't conform.

It apparently recognizes my `numberOfRowsInSection`, because it doesn't complain about that.

This happened after I changed `SeriesViewController` from a `UITableviewController` to a `UIViewController` and added the tableview and cell manually.

Can anybody help?

TIA!

Comment: The return value of `cellForRowAt` is `UITableViewCell`. You must not change it.

Comment: @vadian--

customCell is a UITableViewCell, i.e.:

class CustomTVCell: UITableViewCell {

I've got this in cellForRow:

        let thisCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomTVCell

Comment: @vadian 

I'm likely misunderstand something. I'm not a code veteran. :)

Comment: You can return any subclass of `UITableViewCell`, nevertheless the **signature**  respectively the return value of the datasource method must not be modified.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you, good sir! If you'll post it as an answer, I'll gratefully check and upvote it!